# Translate a Scala Type example to Haskell

Tags: scala, haskell, types, functional-programming

I found a really interesting example in a Scala article and I am wondering how it might be encoded in Haskell.

```
trait Status
trait Open extends Status
trait Closed extends Status

trait Door[S <: Status]
object Door {
  def apply[S <: Status] = new Door[S] {}

  def open[S <: Closed](d: Door[S]) = Door[Open]
  def close[S <: Open](d: Door[S]) = Door[Closed]
}

val closedDoor = Door[Closed]
val openDoor = Door.open(closedDoor)
val closedAgainDoor = Door.close(openDoor)

//val closedClosedDoor = Door.close(closedDoor) // fails to compile
//val openOpenDoor = Door.open(openDoor) // fails to compile
```

This sample encodes at the type level that you can only open a closed `Door`, and only close an open `Door`. My first attempt was just using simple data types but doesn't work as intended:

```
data Status = Open | Closed deriving (Show)
data Door = Door Status deriving (Show)

open :: Door -> Door
open (Door Closed) = Door Open

close :: Door -> Door
close (Door Open) = Door Closed

main = do
  let closedDoor = (Door Closed)
  let openDoor = open closedDoor
  let closedAgainDoor = close openDoor
  let closeClosedDoor = close closedDoor
  let openOpenedDoor = open openDoor
  print closedAgainDoor
```

This actually compiles (unless I try to print `closeClosedDoor` or `openOpenedDoor` which then complains about non-exhaustive patterns in function open, which is obvious)

So I'm trying to figure out if GADTs our Type Families can accomplish this task, but I'm not able to grasp how yet.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In addition to bheklilr's answer, you could use some type extensions to get even closer to the Scala example and rule out non-sensical types like

```hs
Door String
```

Using `DataKinds`, you could effectively disallow the phantom type from being anything but a `Status`.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}

data Door (status :: Status) = Door
data Status = Open | Closed

open :: Door Closed -> Door Open
open _ = Door

close :: Door Open -> Door Closed
close _ = Door
```

Then, with type families, we could even define what it means to "toggle" a door

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

type family Toggle (s :: Status) where
  Toggle Open = Closed
  Toggle Closed = Open

toggle :: Door s -> Door (Toggle s)
toggle Door = Door
```

---

As a closing thought, it may be nicer to use a GADT for `Door` - just so you have two different constructor names. I personally think this reads better

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, DataKinds, TypeFamilies #-}

data Door (status :: Status) where
  OpenDoor :: Door Open
  ClosedDoor :: Door Closed

open :: Door Closed -> Door Open
open _ = OpenDoor

close :: Door Open -> Door Closed
close _ = ClosedDoor

toggle :: Door s -> Door (Toggle s)
toggle OpenDoor = ClosedDoor
toggle ClosedDoor = OpenDoor
```

Comment: You beat me to the `DataKinds` answer.  I didn't want to post it without first checking it compiled, but I had to run `stack setup` first, and that takes a while on a slow network, lol. I like the `toggle` idea with `TypeFamilies` though, hadn't thought of that one.

Comment: Nice, I don't think I would have come to this myself, still learning the advanced features of the language.

Comment: For better inference, `toggle :: (s ~ Toggle t, t ~ Toggle s) => Door s -> Door t`. Or `class Toggled s t | s -> t, t -> s where toggle :: Door s -> Door t`. You could probably use an injective type family for GHC 8, but I don't buy those yet.

Comment: @dfeuer Clever trick for inference! What made you think of it (ie. is this a particular case for a more general pattern)?

Comment: @Alec, it certainly is a special case of a more general pattern! You should always think about it when your type family is injective. But even if it's not, look for opportunities to constrain each type variable in terms of one or more of the others.

Comment: The `lens` package is full of such inference aids if you want to see more examples. Many/most of them are expressed as MPTCs with fundeps, but it's easy to translate to type family language. A good example is `class Tuple1 s t a b | s -> a, t -> b, s b -> t, t a -> s where _1 :: Lens s t a b`.

Comment: The `Tuple1` fundeps record certain facts about how tuple-like types are structured and how type-changing lenses for them can behave. A far less useful constructor class, `class Tuple1P p where _1' :: Lens (p a) (p b) a b`, would effectively have these dependencies automatically.

Answer (score 10):

I would do something like

```
data Open = Open deriving (Show)
data Closed = Closed deriving (Show)
data Door door_state = Door deriving (Show)

open :: Door Closed -> Door Open
open _ = Door

close :: Door Open -> Door Closed
close _ = Door
```

Now there aren't any cases to consider, the state itself is encoded in the type, as with the Scala example.